# Seleccionar todos los clientes cuyo nombre se repita

Tags: mysql, sql

Para sacar todos los clientes sin repetir los nombres es muy fácil.

```
SELECT distinct firstname FROM client
```

Y para sacar todos los clientes cuyo nombre se repite más de una vez tampoco es muy complicado.

```
SELECT count(*), firstname FROM client
GROUP BY firstname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Lo que no logro sacar es un listado de todos los clientes cuyo nombre se repiten, de tal forma que si hay dos "Juan" me muestre el registro de cada uno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos formas

```
SELECT c.*
       FROM client c
       INNER JOIN (SELECT firstname FROM client GROUP BY firstname
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                  ) m
       ON m.firstname = c.firstname;
```

O sino:

```
SELECT c.*
       FROM client c
       WHERE firstname IN (SELECT firstname FROM client GROUP BY firstname
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```